# What is GCP egress?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I want to create an file sharing website, on gcp or amazon aws.
But I do not understand what does that "egress" mean. When I create website, where users can download a file, thats 1gb big, when they download the file, the egress is going to be 1GB, and I need to pay for 1gb? Or it is just when I transfer the 1gb to some other gcp service (some other vm) or to storage etc..

Comment: Egress means data leaving your service (VM in your case). Yes, you will pay for egress. There are exceptions and I recommend consulting the Google pricing page for your products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure it's wherever it's going, with some caveats:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets

E.g. Storage -> Same region instance of app engine doesn't count.

So one of your friends downloads the file? Charged for it. You move the file to a multi-region bucket? Charged for it. You have an app engine application running in the same region as the GCS bucket it's stored in, NOT charged for it, BUT if that app engine application serves up the file to somewhere ELSE, you get charged for THAT egress.

Comment: I'm more concerned with website visitor. My website paints a picture for their browser. Am I charged for it if they are in the same region or in a different region? The HTML, Javascript and CSS sent to their browser will be thousands of bytes on load and then there will be packets for refresh after the initial load.

Comment: You will be charged. The region refers to other Google Cloud services. So it doesn't matter if the customer is in the same geographical region or not, they aren't on GCP, so you would be charged, yes.